# TSQL 'Substring' inside a 'Case' statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring, case

Good day,

I am attempting to pull 3 characters from a string [datatype nvarchar(25)], 
then compare those 3 characters to an 'in',
and if the result is true, it should return a string.

Here is the code:

```
,case
when [column1] = 'this' 
and [column2] is null
and substring([column3], 1, 3) in ('that','those','things') 
then 'different_thing'
else [column1] end as [column4]
```

Comment: `in ('tha', 'tho', 'thi')`?

Comment: apologies, I had to "redact" (for lack of a better term) the strings that I am testing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see the question if the answer is not *compare to substrings of three*. Syntactically this seems fine.

Comment: What I would like to do is take the first three characters from a string, then compare them to a set of static possibilities (within the 'in'), and if the three characters match any of the possibilites, then it should return the result 'different thing'.

Comment: The issue is, I tried this, and I did not get the result that I expected.  I did not get any result equal to 'different thing', when I know for a fact that I should have received that result several times

Comment: Could you please set up an example?

Comment: You've redacted the data, but often the answer to the problem lies in the data. Without seeing it, folks here probably can't provide much more help than just confirming the syntax of your case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're not taking the substring of your static comparators, so if those aren't all *exactly three characters long,* you're gonna have a bad time. I believe that's what Nikola was trying to say, but I'm not sure if it was communicated clearly enough.

Comment: I do understand, the comparisons that I am using are all exactly three characters long. I was able to find another column and data to bounce the comparison off of, and I am getting the response that I needed.  Thanks for the quick help!